# Make listbox selection choose multiple listboxes c#

Tags: c#, listbox

another problem, this one I don't think is as simple as a double like it was last time.

I'm making a listbox that I only want the user to be able to select one option from, and for it change the 'selected state' of the other 2 that are right next to it on the form. The problem is, I can't figure out how to pull whats been selected in the first list box.

I've tried using

```
private void workshopSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i != 5; i++) {
        if (workshopSelect.GetSelected == i){
            NoDBox.SetSelected(i, true);
            feeBox.SetSelected(i, true);
        }
    }
}
```

but the workshopselect.getselected has red squigglies. It says that the == operator cannot be used, and that it "Returns a value indicating whether the specified item is selected" I tried using `(workshopSelect.GetSelected[i])`that didn't work, tried using `(workshopSelect.GetSelected(i))` that didn't work either.

The program should look like this when I select one of the Workshop lines
 [image: program end result]

So my question really is, just what exactly do I use to check the box for what line has been selected?

Comment: Ah.. thanks that helped more then my book lol. I couldn't find that information. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SelectedItem` property instead of `GetSelected` to get selected item. 
Or `SelectedIndex` to get index.

```
if (listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString () == "Supervision skill") 
...

if (listbox1.SelectedIndex == 1) ...
```

Comment: Well the thing was, I was trying to limit how many lines of code I had on here, I only wanted like 5 or 6, not 20+  Having an if statement for each individual string would have been easier to think out, true, but it would have taken a lot more space, that I didn't want  to use. -- Just noticed the last half, for selectedIndex that would have worked as well, in just as many lines as the way I'm doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my `if (workshopSelect.GetSelected(i))` did not work was because well.. I forgot one simple thing, figuring since it said that the == operator was not allowed (which it is). It was because I had to type it out like this `if (workshopSelect.GetSelected(i) == true)` once I changed that, it did exactly what I wanted it to do.